# I want to save messages on the server to the database. how can I do it?

Tags: c#

I want to save messages on the server to the database. how can I do it?

```
    baglanti.Open();
    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("insert into Message (message) 
    values ('" + txtStatus + "')");
    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();//error area //System.InvalidOperationException
```

[full project on gmail drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18Os8jzkRnL7uUT9WBrIigsCecvUjY1Ll)

Comment: This is not C..

Comment: Greetings! Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22706256). Link to your full project won't do.

Comment: Just a thought but is txtStatus a textbox? Because if so, you are probably wanting to store the `.Text` property. However, your sql statement is not safe due to concatenation. This is open to SQL injection and can give user access to your database at a level you don't want them to have.

Comment: yes textbox, this is a simple project that doesn't matter security,I need answers

Comment: time to set a break point and step through the code with the debugger. When you do this, what does the completed string that you're passing to the command look like? Does the inner exception show any more details other than InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @MertAKSU, I have updated my answer with what I think is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of using a parameter to send user inputs to the database. You should be using this method instead of concatenating strings together.

```
baglanti.Open();
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("insert into Message (message) values (@status)", baglanti);
komut.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.varchar, 50).Value = txtStatus.Text
komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

EDIT: Added the connection to the command, I do not see anywhere where you're telling the command what connection to use which would throw that exception. However, if you would have looked further down you should have seen something like `Connection property has not been initialized.`